# Netbeans 7.2 not reflects modification on html, jsp pages

Tags: netbeans-7

Recently i moved from netbeans 6.9 to Netbeans 7.2, while working on 6.9, i have handy functionality of after deployed my project if i do modifications in html or jsp pages i can see when i refresh the page in browser. But while using 7.2 it's not available, so each time i need to build, and deploy for changes get updated.

So i gotta few suggestions like 
1)
Check->Compile on save in project properties
Uncheck->Deploy on save in project properties, but still it's not working.

Any idea what i have missed.
Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

I must say this scenario works fine for me - I don't see any problem. What kind of project are you using - Ant-based or Maven-based? The best thing would be if you can file a P2 issue in the netbeans.org bug database, so we can investigate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I tried renaming the project to a new name not the project folder and re run. It worked for me. Try for yourself.

Nitin.